# What is a body strength?

Tags: muscle, strength, bodybuilding

I want to know what is the body strength? Is that muscle building help for make a body strength?

Answer (score 0):

Strength is dictated by the ability of your central nervous system to use as much muscle fibers as possible.

Having big muscles doesn't make a person stronger, having big muscles makes the person slightly more resistant to strength training, thus making it easier to build strenght.

Big muscles require more effort to reach failure, having big muscles allows you to use heavy weights for more time so your nervous system receives a bigger stimulation.

Comment: Can you explain it in more deeply?